# How to run Codeigniter on IP address instead domain name?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to start Codeigniter in IP address instead domain name:

So, I have configuration:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://152.80.141.23/';
```

And routing:

```
$route['recovery'] = 'registration/recovery';
```

When I try to call route: `http://152.80.141.23/recovery`

I get error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /recovery was not found on this server.
```

**Htaccess is:**

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

**My latest config file is:**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
$config['site_lang_url']    = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: There is no need to set IP address in `base_url` You can always visit a website with it's IP address.

Comment: are you running application locally..(on windows?)?? if so have you edited 'host' file ??

Comment: Okay, I tried also: `$config['base_url'] = '';` but others page dont work

Comment: No. I run this on Ubuntu Server 16, Apache

Comment: Is `.htaccess` file in root or in subdirectory of web server's public location?

Comment: Files `.htaccess` is in root directory near `index.php` file

Comment: So, index.php works, but others routes are not

Comment: Is `http://152.80.141.23/index.php/recovery` working URL?

Comment: Yes, it works fine :) Then I sholud escape index.php

Comment: How can I do that for IP?

Comment: Not best to use IP for url because some of the links will not work like css and others It is best to set it like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project-name/';` WARNING: You MUST set this value!

Comment: I can not set localhost and domain name, only ip

Comment: But I have public DNS name

Comment: I tried, it does not work too

Comment: I get only error: `Not Found

The requested URL /contacts was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 52.40.141.253 Port 80`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/


# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```